Kubernetes image registry - local or remote?
My (lab/learning) Kubernetes cluster is running using containerd as a runtime (CRI). 
I am trying to figure out if my system does have local image registry OR the following output displays only references/links to remote registries where actual images are kept?
crictl image list
IMAGE                                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE
docker.io/calico/cni                       v3.26.0             5d6f5c26c6554       93.3MB
docker.io/calico/node                      v3.26.0             44f52c09decec       87.6MB
docker.io/library/busybox                  latest              ba5dc23f65d4c       2.16MB
docker.io/library/nginx                    latest              92b11f67642b6       70.5MB
docker.io/library/redis                    latest              170a1e90f8436       51.4MB
k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server   v0.6.2              25561daa66605       28.1MB
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns            v1.10.1             ead0a4a53df89       16.2MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                 v1.28.7             123aa721f941b       28.1MB
registry.k8s.io/pause                      3.8                 4873874c08efc       311kB
registry.k8s.io/pause                      3.9                 e6f1816883972       322kB


The output of crictl image list doesn't have anything to do with image registries.
The crictl image list command is analagous to the docker image ls command -- both show you images that live in the local container runtime, typically because there are -- or were -- containers running on that system that required those images.
An image registry is a repository of images not associated with your local container runtime. You interact with a registry explicitly via docker pull or implicitly by starting a container that requires an image not available locally.

Thank you, that makes sense and it answers my question.
So, as I understand it now, by default (at least in my lab cluster) there is no local registry and each node keeps images in "local container runtime".
However, i understand i can create LOCAL registry and "ask" cluster (all nodes) to use it for keeping pulling from images - am i correct?
